# NASM: little-endian WORD constant

Tags: assembly, nasm, endianness

I want to make WORD variable in little endian without manually converting it, for example:

```
SECTION .data
    variable1: dw 2  ; <-- How to make 2 little-endian without manually writing db 0x02, 0x00?
```

Maybe NASM has builtin macro or you can suggest your one?

Comment: It's already little endian (otherwise loading it would give the wrong value)

Comment: @harold OK, but how to make it big-endian if it's already little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86 is little-endian so `dw 2` already does assemble the same as `db 2, 0`.

**To assemble big-endian integers**, you just need to swap the bytes.  For a 2-byte x86 `word`, that's simple, just rotate by 8, which we can do with a NASM [single-line macro](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.2)  and [arithmetic expression](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5.9)

```
; mask before right shifting because NASM expressions are 64-bit integers
; and we don't want to shift in ones from negative numbers 
%define  swap_word(x)  ( (x<<8) | ((x&0xFFFF)>>>8) )
```

`(...) & 0xffff` isn't needed, NASM doesn't warn about truncation even without.  It would make a difference if used like `dd swap_word(-2)` (`FF FE FF FF` instead of `FF FE 00 00`)

NASM listing from some uses (`nasm -l /dev/stdout foo.asm`), with spaces put between the bytes because even though it's dumping individual bytes, it by default crams them together like 0002 which is confusing in this case when we're messing around with big-endian data:

```
  00 02                    dw swap_word(2)
  FF FE                    dw swap_word(-2)
  00 02                    dw 0x0200
  FF FE                    dw 0xFEFF         ; same thing done manually
```